# iOS Tab Bar Item Custom Images

Tags: ios, xcode, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

I have been attempting to create a tabbed application with tab bar items that are custom images, but no matter what I do there is always a tint over it.

Is there any way to use the image and preserve all the original colors without it automatically covering it with a tint?

Thank you, any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution

```
[[UIView appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! Would I put that in the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` function in the appDelegate?

I tried something similar before (I set the tint of the UITabBarItem to clearColor), and it's gave the same result: when the item is selected it ends up being actually "clear"(look like there is no icon for the tab bar item), and when it is not selected it still has a grey tint but I can't see the original image since it is just a tint overlay of the image :(

Is there something else I have to do? Or do I need to put that piece of code somewhere else?

Comment: Also, I'm using Swift, I don't think it would make a difference but maybe I messed up translating the code?

        `UIView.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.clearColor();` is what I think the Swift conversion would be